# How to make sure that the numerical value is not replaced by NaN in the lower method in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have dataset like this:

```
Login:
ABC
123a
12
```

I wrote the code:

```
def fun(x):
    if x.str.isdigit():
        return x
    else:
        return x.str.lower()

Dataset['Login'].apply(fun)
```

I have this result:

```
Login:
abc
123a
NaN
```

How do I get rid of NaN so that there is a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is possible use `try-except` statement for lower values if possible, else return same value:

```
Dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Login':['ABC','123a',12]})
    
def fun(x):
    try:
       return x.lower()
    except:
       return x
   
Dataset['Login'] = Dataset['Login'].apply(fun)
print (Dataset)
  Login
0   abc
1  123a
2    12
```

Another solution with [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
Dataset['Login'] = Dataset['Login'].str.lower().fillna(Dataset['Login'])
print (Dataset)
  Login
0   abc
1  123a
2    12
```

Comment: Do not convert to small letters

Comment: @MarySmith - For me working well, added sample data to answer.